# Angular 2 debugging - What events cause angular 2 services to clear out all their data?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

app.component.ts is blank, the html just renders my body-component. I inject the services into a few other components whose templates render in body-components template/router-outlet.

In my service I do a http to fetch data from server:

```
fetchData() {
  return this.http.get(this.url + 'events')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

in my component, if my service does not contain data I make a request to fetch data but it is always undefined when I change routes even after the data is loaded:

```
    constructor (private router:Router,
               private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
               private eventService: EventService,
               private authService: AuthService) {

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.eventService.events == undefined) {
      this.eventService.fetchData()
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.events.sort(function (a, b) {
              let x = new Date(a['date']);
              let y = new Date(b['date']);
              return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
            });
            this.eventService.setEvents(data);
            this.events = data;
            // localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(this.events));
            // localStorage.setItem('eventRefresh', String(new Date()));
          });
    }
    else {
        this.events = this.eventService.getEvents();
    }
  }
```

my routes:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: 'users/login/:', component: AuthComponent},
    {path: 'tickets', component: SellTicketComponent},
    {path: 'tickets:', component: SellTicketComponent},
    {path: 'success/:', component: TicketSoldComponent},
    {path: 'profile', component: UserProfileComponent, canActivate: [SellTicketGuard]},
    {path: 'create', component: CreateeventComponent, canActivate: [GuestlistGuard]},
    {path: 'viewguests', component: ViewAttendingComponent, canActivate: [GuestlistGuard]},
    {path: 'termsofuse', component: PopupComponent},
    {path: 'terms', component: PopupComponent, canActivate: [SellTicketGuard]},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'} // wildcard. Could make a 404 page.
```

app.module.ts:

```
//Services:
import { EventService } from './services/event.service';
import { AuthService } from "./services/auth.service";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    routing,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [EventService, AuthService, CreateEventGuard, SellTicketGuard, GuestlistGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How do I make an angular 2 app load every route and then operate entirely in the client without clearing out services data or reloading the page on route change?

This is a broad question because I have no idea what the problem is - what angular 2 app events cause angular services to clear all their data/variable property values? Whenever I navigate to my root route all my data from both my services is cleared out and has to be re-fetched from the server because all the service variables are undefined.

To summarise my situation: I am providing my services in app.module.ts, importing them in my individual components and injecting them in their constructors. I have an angular 2 single page application and everything is rendered from one router-outlet or component specific outlets on the same page and when I use this.router.navigate or a routerLink on the navbar to get around my app components, every time it clears out the data I have stored in my services, specifically an array of JSON objects, and it renders the one component again and does its ngOnInit which checks whether there is data in the service and because there isn't it pulls the data again from the database. I would like this data to persist so the client is not hitting my server every 2 seconds for the same data, how do I achieve this without using localStorage? Would some sort of lazy loading do this?

Comment: Maybe you can add some code to your question? A service should hold it's data between loading of components so my guess is you're doing something wrong..

Comment: Theres way too much code to paste, its an entire massive project. What causes a service to lose all of its data? Is it  that I am importing it and providing it in app.module.ts and not app.component.ts? Does navigation to app-root cause services to reload fresh?

Comment: could it be this?      {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'} // wildcard. or this [routerLink]="['/']" on my home button

Comment: You don't have a component registered in the router for "" route?

Comment: When I do it causes my page to load twice, two bodies, one on top of the other. One navbar. I have no idea why:  appcomponent.html:  <app-appnavbar></app-appnavbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>


<app-body></app-body>


<app-events></app-events>


<footer></footer> for router path: {path: '', component: AppComponent}.  It renders one navbar, body, app-events, footer, body, app-events, footer. No idea why. I assume it has something to do with the router-outlet but still dont get it.

Comment: Probably because your selector for app.component is app-body and it gets loaded both through outlet and it's own tag.

Comment: No app-body is just a jumbotron. Also it doesnt fix my main problem of services losing all their data on navigating

Comment: I dont get angular routing at all, some of my routes just insert the template when I press the routerLink and some reload the page. Why cant they all just insert the template and never reload the page? and why do some reload and some dont? I coded them all the same

Comment: Well, the problem would be that, if you don't have a defined route for your index page, it would treat it as a href link separate from router and reload the page. Regarding other pages, it could be something with how you implemented your guards, it could be the same issue if you're navigating to the index page, if guard fails.

Comment: Yes but even when I add {path: '', component: AppComponent} my services data is not persisting

Comment: Can you also paste your app.component in the question?

Comment: Theres nothing in it except @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'}) and the html which renders all my other components <app-appnavbar></app-appnavbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-body></app-body>


<app-events></app-events>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136891/discussion-between-adnan-a-and-seaned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** With provided code and some other insights through comments, we can safely conclude it's not an injector issue, but router issue as some of the routes are reloading the page completely and renewing the service instances in injectors.

Replacing the `routerLink` directives with `router.navigate` functions solved the problem.

**Original answer:**

Well, since you've provided no code, I'll take a wild guess that you're declaring the service inside component `providers` list. This will cause the injector to create a new instance of the service every time that component is initialized.

Injector tree maps the component tree, which means that each component has its own injector that will override the parent injector. So, in order to have a singleton service, you need to declare the service only in your **root** node (module).

Comment: I am only declaring the service in app.module.ts and importing it in my other components. I have no providers array in any other component. Am i supposed to provide it in the root app.component.ts and store the data there? Or is it fine to just provide it in app.module.ts

Comment: import {AuthService} from "../services/auth.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-events',
  templateUrl: './events.component.html',
})
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor (private router:Router,
               private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
               private eventService: EventService,
               private authService: AuthService) {

Comment: A service needs to be added as [providers] in your @NgModule and then DI'ed in your components. So if that is what you're doing, the issue might lie somewhere else. Is your service maybe using Observables? And are you re-subscribing to those from every component? It's hard determining the cause without any code..

Comment: if I do {path: '', component: AppComponent} then my home page loads the entire page 2x one on top of the other lol

Comment: ill edit my original post to post some code, I am using observables and subscribing to them yes

Comment: I would appreciate if you pasted app.module, app.component and your routes. Thanks.